# Find the probability that the two letters selected at random from the word “Television” are both a) vowels b) consonants

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Since there are 2i's, 2 e and one o..the possible events is
$C(2,2)+C(2,2)+C(3,2)=5$

The total possible outcomes is $C(2,2)+C(2,2)+C(8,2)=30$

Therefore the probability of both vowels is  $$\frac{5}{30}=\frac{1}{6}$$

and it matches the answer as well. For second case i assumed

probability of both vowels + probability of both consonants =1

$\frac{1}{6}$+probability of both consonants=1

probability of both consonants$=1-\frac{1}{6}$

probability of both consonants = $\frac{5}{6}$

But answer is $\frac{1}{3}$

What is wrong here..Thanks in advance.

Comment: abstract algebra ? Really ?

Comment: You left out the probability of one vowel & one consonant.

Comment: But I don't see why $1/6$ is right for two vowels. I don't understand your calculation. If the letters are being chosen without replacement, there should be $C(5,2)=10$ favorable events, and $C(10,2)=45$ total events, for probability $10/45=2/9$, not $1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

The word "Television" as 10 letters.  5 are vowel and 5 are consonants.

If you pick the letters at random, every letter being equally likely, the probability the first letter chosen is a consonant is 5/10= 1/2.  If that happens there are 9 letters left, 4 of them consonants.  The probability the second letter chosen is a consonant is 4/9.  The probability the first two letters are consonants is (1/2)(4/9)= 2/9.

If you pick the letters at random, every letter being equally likely, the probability the first letter chosen is a vowel is 5/10= 1/2.  If that happens there are 9 letters left, 4 of them vowels.  The probability the second letter chosen is a vowel is 4/9.  The probability the first two letters are vowels is also (1/2)(4/9)= 2/9.

The original question was only about "two consonants" or "two vowels" but Gerry Myerson asked about "one vowel" and "one consonant".  The probability that the first letter chosen is a consonant is again 1/2.  In that case there are 9 letters left, 5 of them vowels so the probability the second letter is a vowel is 5/9.  The probability the the two letters are a consonant and a vowel, *in that order*, is (1/2)(5/9)= 5/18. A similar argument show that the probability of a vowel and a consonant, *in that order*, is also 5/18.  The probability of   a vowel and a consonant,in either order, is 5/18+ 5/18= 10/18= 5/9.

Of course, 2/9+ 2/9+ 5/9= 9/9= 1.

Comment: But my question the sum selection of two vowel and two constonatns shouldn't be equal to 1? Since there are only two choice either vowel or constontant..so probaility of selection of vowel plus probability of selection of consonants must be equal to 1.

Comment: No, Sagar – once again, you are overlooking the possibility that one of the two chosen letters is a vowel, while the other chosen letter is a consonant.

Comment: Do you understand it now, @Sagar ?